# Проблема с атрибутом в классе python

Tags: python-3.x

Пытаюсь разобрать в классах python3, но возникает вот такая проблема.
Код:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name, phone_number,password):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.password = password
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        print("Name: " + self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title()
        +"\n" + "Phone number: " + "+7" + str(self.phone_number) + '\n'
        + "User password: " + str(self.password))

    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello " + self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title() 


+ '.')

class Admin(User):

    def __init___(self,first_name,last_name,phone_number,password):
        super().__init__(first_name,last_name,phone_number,password)
        self.privilegis = [
        'разрешено добавлять сообщения',
        'разрешено удалять пользователей',
        'разрешено банить пользователей'
        ]

    def show_privilegis(self):              
        print("Привилегии администратора: ")  
        for priv in self.privilegis:    `"""Здесь появляется ошибка"""`
            print("\t\t  " + priv)



users = Admin("Froggy", 'cat', "94165146", '12345')
users.show_privilegis()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Привилегии администратора: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    users.show_privilegis()
  File "test.py", line 30, in show_privilegis
    for priv in self.privilegis:
AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute 'privilegis'
```

Непонимаю в чём именно ошибка. Буду рад если скажите с чем она связана .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас лишнее нижнее подчеркивание в классе `Admin` в функции `__init__`

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, password):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.password = password
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        print("Name: " + self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title()
              + "\n" + "Phone number: " + "+7" + str(self.phone_number) + '\n'
              + "User password: " + str(self.password))

    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello " + self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title() + '.')


class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number, password):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, phone_number, password)
        self.privilegis = ['разрешено добавлять сообщения',
                           'разрешено удалять пользователей',
                           'разрешено банить пользователей'
                           ]

    def show_privilegis(self):
        print("Привилегии администратора: ")
        for priv in self.privilegis:
            print("\t\t  " + priv)


users = Admin("Froggy", 'cat', "94165146", '12345')
users.show_privilegis()
```